# How to handle success/error flash messages from Rethinkdb in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, rethinkdb, flash-message, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to get the success or insuccess of a query to my RethinkDB in the Phoenix Framework through a Flash message. However I don't know the correct signature to retrieve the result message from RethinkDB in my code block.

```
def index(conn, _params) do

  #Query that creates a table in the database
    table_create("contentText")
    |> Basedados.Database.run
      # List all elements of a table from the database
    q = table("contentText")
      |> Basedados.Database.run #Run the query through the database
      |> IO.inspect
    conn
    |> put_flash(:error, "Some Message")
    |> put_flash(:info, "Another Message")
    |> render "index.html", contentText: q #Render users searched on the users template
  end
```

**EDIT:** Okay I found out that there is supposed to be an errors field along the lines of:

```
%RethinkDB.Record{data: %{"deleted" => 0, "errors" => 0, "generated_keys" => ["15cc4e19-fc72-4c19-b3a5-47141b6a63e0"], "inserted" => 1, "replaced" => 0, "skipped" => 0, "unchanged" => 0}}
```

However I don't seem to have it (I tried it like `q.errors` and `q.data.errors`) and I get an error every time.
The error I'm testing is if the database table does not exist (I change contentText to something else entirely).

I'm able to do some error checking with data:

```
q = table("contentText")
  |> Basedados.Database.run #Run the query through the database

if is_nil(q.data) do
  conn
  |> put_flash(:error, "Error")
  |> render "index.html", contentText: "failed" #Render users searched on the users template
else
  conn
  |> put_flash(:info, "Sucess")
  |> render "index.html", contentText: q #Render users searched on the users template
end
```

However this seems like a limited solution as it only detects if there is data in the message. An error can be something else entirely. And since that field seems to count them I would like to get that value and use it in my condition instead (if errors > 0).
What do I need to get that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `q.data["errors"])` instead of `q.data.errors`.

according to the issue [hamiltop/rethinkdb-elixir#59](https://github.com/hamiltop/rethinkdb-elixir/issues/59), you can use `q.data["r"]` on failure.

Comment: That appears to do solve that part of the issue. But I'm still missing on how to chain this to a flash message.

Comment: No. What I mean is that I want to trigger a flash message with the error message on the client side. I know how to perform them on my client side, but I don't know how to send a trigger for one from my channel.

Comment: According to the [Phoenix documentation](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/controllers#section-flash-messages) you are doing right. If you want to send the error RethinDB just change the `put_flash(:error, "Error")` to `put_flash(:error, Enum.join(q.data["r"], "\n"))`.